# I have to re-enable Bluetooth or open settings before my keyboard will connect after docking my Windows 10 laptop

Tags: laptop, keyboard, bluetooth, docking-station

I use an HP ZBook 15 G2 with Windows 10 as my laptop. At home, I use its corresponding docking station (HP 230W Docking Station) to connect it to my external monitors. I also have a Logitech K380 Bluetooth keyboard that I use both at home (when the laptop is docked) and on the go (when it's not).

When I get home, dock my laptop (which is in sleep mode at that point), and wake it, the Bluetooth keyboard can never connect. The Bluetooth icon is visible in the system tray, but I have to either turn Bluetooth off and on again or just open the Bluetooth settings (in the Settings app) without touching anything (!) before the keyboard will connect.

This only happens when I dock and wake the previously undocked laptop, i.e. when I sleep and re-wake the laptop while in the dock, or restart the laptop while in the dock, the keyboard connects just fine.

I've already tried re-installing the (HP-provided) Intel Bluetooth driver via 'Apps & features', but that didn't help. I've also tried uninstalling the driver altogether via the same method, but Device Manager still shows the same driver version (i.e. it seems like either Windows ships with this driver, or Intel's uninstallation utility is broken).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to go to Device Manager > Bluetooth > Intel Wireless Bluetooth, open the 'Power Management' tab, and uncheck the 'Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power' box.